# ORA-06550: line 13, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the "UPDATE" ORA-06550: line 15, column 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: plsql

EXIT WHEN 
   update table set counter=1 where  counter is NULL;
       -- LOOP until condition is met 
  END LOOP;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXIT WHEN FLAG=1/*give some exit criteria here .You wrote update statement which was incorrect*/; 
--update table set counter=1 where counter is NULL;
-- LOOP until condition is met 
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXIT WHEN` expects a boolean expression as its argument, but you have supplied an `UPDATE` statement instead, which is not an expression at all.

You need to specify what condition(s) must be met for the loop to exit.